# I cant seem to install Homebrew on my system

Tags: homebrew

Using Mac OS Sierra (Version 10.12.1).... following is the error I get ... Please help

```
Amits-MacBook-Pro:~ amitsubba$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

==> This script will install:

/usr/local/bin/brew

/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew

/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

/usr/local/Homebrew

==> The following new directories will be created:

/usr/local/lib

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort

==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/lib

Password:

> mkdir: /usr/local/lib: Not a directory
>
> Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/lib

```
Amits-MacBook-Pro:~ amitsubba$
```

Comment: What the version of your OS X? (Please edit the question to add the information)

Comment: Version 10.12.1 @equal_I2

Comment: I think you are falling foul of *System Integrity Protection* - https://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete lib file in /usr/local:

```
cd /usr/local  
rm lib
```

Also give full permissions to directories Homebrew and Cellar in the same directory:

```
sudo chmod 777 Homebrew/
sudo chmod 777 Cellar/
```

And then run below commands:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local; brew update
rm -rf /usr/local/.git
```

Now try to install homebrew using ruby as usual.

Comment: `chmod 777` is bad even for home PC

Answer (score 0):

Manually create `/usr/local/lib` and then retry installing.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and it was because I already had a simlink at usr/local/bin

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 Caskroom
drwxrwxrwx  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 Cellar
drwxrwxr-x  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 Frameworks
drwxrwxrwx  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 Homebrew
lrwxr-xr-x  1 michael.huff  admin  24 Feb 25 16:54 bin -> /usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf
drwxrwxr-x  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 etc
drwxrwxr-x  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 include
drwxr-xr-x  3 michael.huff  admin  96 Feb 28 23:32 jamf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          wheel  64 Mar 18 14:09 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 opt
drwxrwxr-x  2 michael.huff  admin  64 Mar 18 11:40 sbin
drwxrwxr-x  3 michael.huff  admin  96 Mar 18 11:40 share
drwxrwxr-x  3 michael.huff  admin  96 Mar 18 11:40 var
```

All I had to do was `sudo rm /usr/local/bin` and then try reinstalling brew again.